# How do I select whether the routine continues based on the participant's response?

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, psychopy, routines

I want to create an experiment in PsychoPy Builder that conditionally shows a second routine to participants based on their keyboard response.

In the task, I have a loop that first goes through a routine where participants have three options to respond ('left','right','down') and only if they select 'left', regardless of the correct answer, should they see a second routine that asks a follow-up question to respond to. The loop should then restart with routine 1 each time.

I've tried using bits of code in the "begin experiment" section as such:

```
if response.key=='left':
    continueRoutine=True
elif response.key!='left':
    continueRoutine=False
```

But here I get an error saying response.key is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your keyboard component is actually called `response`, the attribute you are looking for is called `response.keys`. It is pluralised as it returns a list rather than a single value. This is because it is capable of storing multiple keypresses. Even if you only specify a single response, it will still be returned as a list containing just that single response (e.g. `['left']` rather than `'left'`). So you either need to extract just one element from that list (e.g. `response.keys[0]`) and test against that, or use a construction like `if 'left' in response.keys` to check inside the list.

Secondly, you don't need to have a check that assigns `True` to `continueRoutine`, as it defaults to being `True` at the beginning of a routine. So it is only setting it to `False` that results in any action. So you could simply do something like this:

```
if not 'left' in response.keys:
    continueRoutine = False
```

Lastly, for PsychoPy-specific questions, you might get better support via the dedicated forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org as it allows for more to-and-fro discussion than the single question/answer structure here at SO.

Comment: Thank you so much. I forgot that the Psychopy forum even existed. Much appreciated.

Comment: Sure. Please mark the answer as "accepted" if it worked for you, as a guide to future readers.